# My mirror gave me a 403 response

Tags: sudo, wget

```
sudo wget http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/initrd.gz
```

This command did not work for me. The terminal just shows me this message:

```
http request sent, waiting for response ... 403 Forbiddedn
```

I'm actually trying to install a VM in xen hypervisor that I already installed in Ubuntu... I really need help.

Comment: Browser their page: http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ They say that the mirror is closed so, thats why you can't download anything anymore from **that** mirror.

Answer (score 3):

The Argonne National Laboratory shut down their public mirror on February 1, 2015. You will need to choose a new mirror.

You can do this through several methods. The two most common are:

1. Edit the mirror manually in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Through *System Settings >> Software and Updates >> Download from ...* And choose a new mirror from the drop-down list or use the wizard (the choice labeled *other* to make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you open that URL in your web browser the page says

> We regret to inform you that public access to the Argonne software
>   mirror will no longer be available as of February 1, 2015. The service
>   will continue to be available onsite to Argonne employees, but offsite
>   access will require an Argonne VPN connection.

You'll need to use another mirror instead of mirror.anl.gov, for example us.archive.ubuntu.com:

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/initrd.gz

Comment: i tried this mirror and it worked , thank you very much